# Displaying a tree like json in a pageview.builder

Tags: flutter

```
  [
    {
            "createdBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
            "createdDate": "2023-06-19T00:06:11.329665Z",
            "lastModifiedBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
            "lastModifiedDate": "2023-06-19T00:06:11.329665Z",
            "id": "0bbdb0fb-fa6a-4672-8fa3-a6afaa7102e0",
            "title": "Do you have a sibling or parent that is a Canadian citizen?",
            "hint": "hint",
            "options": "Yes,No",
            "description": "description",
            "priority": 40,
            "type": "RADIO",
            "dependsOnValue": null,
            "dependents": [
                {
                    "createdBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
                    "createdDate": "2023-06-19T00:08:19.352753Z",
                    "lastModifiedBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
                    "lastModifiedDate": "2023-06-19T00:08:19.352753Z",
                    "id": "05368867-c64a-4600-8967-a98d4f986ecf",
                    "title": "What is the relationship?",
                    "hint": "hint",
                    "options": "Father,Mpther,Brother,Sister",
                    "description": "description",
                    "priority": 41,
                    "type": "DROPDOWN",
                    "dependsOnValue": "Yes",
                    "dependents": [
                        {
                            "createdBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
                            "createdDate": "2023-06-19T00:16:01.804350Z",
                            "lastModifiedBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
                            "lastModifiedDate": "2023-06-19T00:16:01.804350Z",
                            "id": "246c5fb5-e528-455a-a461-17dec11271b1",
                            "title": "Which province do they reside",
                            "hint": "hint",
                            "options": "Alberta,British Columbia,Manitoba,New Brunswick,Newfoundland and Labrador,Nova Scotia,Ontario,Prince Edward Island,Quebec,Saskatchewan",
                            "description": "description",
                            "priority": 42,
                            "type": "DROPDOWN",
                            "dependsOnValue": "Father,Mpther,Brother,Sister",
                            "dependents": null,
                            "answer": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "answer": null
                }
            ],
            "answer": null
        },
         {
            "createdBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
            "createdDate": "2023-06-19T22:08:59.389956Z",
            "lastModifiedBy": "Francisca@migra.co",
            "lastModifiedDate": "2023-06-19T22:08:59.389956Z",
            "id": "5a22ffa3-3327-4429-a8b7-28822161f4e7",
            "title": "Have you travelled out of your country of residence before?",
            "hint": "hint",
            "options": "Yes,No",
            "description": "description",
            "priority": 50,
            "type": "RADIO",
            "dependsOnValue": null,
            "dependents": null,
            "answer": null
        },
  ]
```

Now, I'm displaying this in a pageview.builder in flutter. I'm having issue displaying the dependents. What I'm trying to achieve is when a user selects an option and it matches the dependsonValue, i want to display in the list.

For expamle in priority 40, if the user selects yes, it display the dependent where the dependsonValue is yes else if the user selects no, it should display priority 50.